# Loop over 2 lists to create seperate dfs from multiple excel worksheets

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, xlsxwriter

I've read in the below excel workbook which has 40 sheets. The below reads in all the worksheets:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = None)
```

All the worksheets have identical columns, but the relevant columns start at different rows in each worksheet, so I'm writing the below to create a df from each sheet:

```
df2 = df[Sheet_Name]
df2.columns = df2.iloc[20]
```

I could replicate this code 40 times with the relevant row index, but there has to be a function with a loop that can clean the code.

I was thinking of having 2 lists, sheet name & row index, which the function iterates over to create a separate df for each worksheet.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using next()

```
new_dfs = list()
indexes = iter([20, 12, 20])
for sheet in df:
    new_df = df[sheet]
    new_df.colunms = new_df.iloc[next(indexes)]
    new_dfs.append(new_df)
```

I did not run this code, but the idea is worth trying

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).